# Pegar referencia da linha na tabela com JSF(Primefaces)

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, datatable

Tenho um cenário que apresenta algo esquisito e não entendi o porquê deste comportamento. Utilizando JSF com Primefaces, tenho um **Datatable** com alguns (vários) valores que vem do **Banco de Dados** e são exibidos nas colunas. Meu cenário apresenta as seguintes dependências:

JSF - **Primefaces** (Datatable) > **ManagedBeans** > DAOS (Metodos de acessos aos dados) > **Models** (JPA)

Meu datatable está assim:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />
    <p:dataTable id="calls" var="call" value="#{callMB.allCalls}" rows="25" paginator="true" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PageLinks} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" rowsPerPageTemplate="25,50,100" paginatorPosition="bottom" draggableColumns="true" scrollable="true" emptyMessage="Nenhum registro foi encontrado.">
                    <c:facet name="header">
                        Consulta de Chamadas
                    </c:facet>
                    <p:column headerText="Info" width="200" style="text-align: center">
                        <p:commandLink value="Ver Mais" type="button"
                            oncomplete="PF('callDialog').show();" update=":form:dialog">
                            <c:setPropertyActionListener value="#{call}"
                                target="#{callMB.selectedCall}"></c:setPropertyActionListener>
                        </p:commandLink>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Call ID" filterBy="#{call.callId}"
                        filterMatchMode="exact" width="500">
                        <h:outputText value="#{call.callId}"></h:outputText>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
                <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Modal Dialog" widgetVar="callDialog"
                    modal="true" height="100">
                    <h:outputText value="#{callMB.selectedCall.callId}"></h:outputText>
                </p:dialog>
            </h:form>
```

Meu ManagedBean está assim:

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class CallMB {

    private List<Call> allCalls;
    private Call selectedCall;

    public Call getSelectedCall() {
        return selectedCall;
    }

    public void setSelectedCall(Call selectedCall) {
        this.selectedCall = selectedCall;
    }

    public List<Call> getAllCalls() {
        allCalls = new CallDAO().retrieveAllCalls();
        RouteDAO routeDAO = new RouteDAO();
        for (Call call : allCalls) {
            call.setRouteName(routeDAO.retrieveRouteByCode(call.getRouteCode()).getName());
        }
        return allCalls;
    }
}
```

Porém quando clico em no meu link "Ver Mais" ele está buscando um id totalmente diferente do que está na linha.

Comment: Tente adicionar o atributo `rowKey="#{call.callId}"` no seu data table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema estava ocorrendo pois quando eu clicava no meu commandlink, ao abrir o showdialog era destruido e recarregado meu ManagedBean, logo, meu array era recarregado com as informações mais recentes. Resolvi adicionando um metodo init() anotado como @PostConstruct para carregar o array e corrigido o escopo do meu ManagedBeans de @ApplicationScoped para @SessionScoped.